# Inject properties after object creation

Tags: java, spring

I have a class that has some dynamic attributes which I received on the constructor.
Other properties on this same class are/can be injected by spring.

I want to know if this is possible and how should I config my application. I using spring 3 and xml configuration.

Here is an example:

```
class MyClass {
   private MyClass2 obj2; // should be injected by spring
   private Long myId;

   public MyClass(Long dynamicId) {
      myId = dynamicId;
   }

   public void doSomehting() {
      obj2.doOtherStuff(this);
   }
}
```

So, what I want, since I must create MyClass dynamically, is that after I call new MyClass(1234), the obj2 gets injected by Spring.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an ObjectFactory to retrieve the bean from the di-container. If you wrap this factory in a factory object of your own, you can set any property and still have the bean managed by Spring. Since you want the bean to have some dynamically set property think it through whether you need a singleton-scoped bean (default) or a prototype one.

If you intend to do this from xml config you need to muck around with [objectfactorycreatingfactorybean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean.html). Spring documentation is excellent, just follow the example.

If you do annotation-based configuration, you just need to autowire the ObjectFactory. Note that YourClass has to be declared as a bean too!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's not possible. It looks like you want a (*scary music*) factory.

```
class MyClassFactory {

  private final MyClass2 object;

  public(MyClass2 object) {
    this.object = object;
  }

  public createMyClass(Lond id) {
    return new MyClass(id, object);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create an instance of MyClass dynamically with the new operator, that instance is outside of Spring's bean factory, so Spring cannot inject anything. You really have two options, from what I can see.
1) Make MyClass a prototype bean so Spring gives you a new instance every time you need it. You would need to then define obj2 as a property to be set (or Autowired).
2) Inject obj2 via Spring into the class that is creating the instance of MyClass and make obj2 a constructor argument so you have to inject it.

My 0.02 from what I read from your question. A note of caution, when creating a new instance in Java, it is always outside the bean factory and all work performed outside the bean factory looses the Spring proxy behaviors. Be very careful here, you can get yourself into a rabbit hole that can be hard to track down.